# What is the meaning of &rand= in the URL `php?L=domain_name&P=smart@domain_name&rand=0.3747900246217`

Tags: php, url, server

I was viewing a page from from time to time. It displayed results after collecting them from a php server, I inspected the page and got found out the url accessing to receive the data from the server.

It did this every few seconds and every time it did this, the 16-17 numbers after `&rand=0.` were different. What is `&rand=0` followed by 16-17 numbers and what is its use?

Pressed Ctrl + Shift + C to inspect to page. That's where I got the URL the website was visiting every few seconds.

The URL that it visited every few seconds is of the form:
`http://Domain_Name/getMobilityData.php?L=Domain_Name@Domain_name&P=smart@nist&rand=0.4620007141256325` and the decimal part after rand changed every time.

Comment: The rand generates a random number. This is usually done so that it loads the page each time without using a cache copy.

Comment: So, if I randomly generate 16 numbers and add them after rand=0. , should I expect the page to load without using a cache copy ?

Comment: Yes, you can do this on any page even.

Comment: this is called a "cache buster".

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the info, I didn't know it had a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, the addition of the `rand` variable is to prevent a browser cache or frontend cache from preventing the request reaching the server. This is helpful where the server wishes to see every request, e.g. to collect hit data.

Importantly, the format of this is just the same as any other query string variable, so if your endpoint looks like `getMobilityData.php?L=Domain_Name@Domain_name&P=smart@nist&rand=0.4620007141256325`, then the remote script is getting these variables:

- L (value = "Domain_Name")
- P (value = "smart@nist")
- rand (value = "0.4620007141256325", which could be cast to a floating point number)

Another key point is that it does not matter what the cache buster is called; the author chose `rand`, but it could equally have been `lizard`, or indeed anything that is not already in use. Furthermore, the value can be anything at all, except that to bust caches effectively, it must be highly likely not to have ever been used before. It does not have to be 16-17 digits long - it could have been 64 digits, and it could have been hexadecimal, or 32 characters, and all-alpha, etc.